# How to log speed test results with wget? Or other solutions to check ISP performance

Tags: internet, wget

I'm trying to set up a script I can schedule to run hourly or so that appends something like 
[timestamp] [speed] (and ideally [variance])
to a log file that I can turn into pretty graphs. The command I have now is:

```
    wget --output-document=/dev/null --append-output=/home/(myUsername)/Desktop/speedlog.txt --report-speed=bits http://dallas2.testmy.net/dl-100MB
```

The output I'm getting in terminal is way more than what I need. How do I cut this down?

Additionally, I'd like to have some more of the metrics like tesmy.net puts out, like middle variance so I can put error bars on my plot or show erratic performance. What kind of math goes into that calculation? Am I reinventing someone's wheel here?

Comment: ping ? google test speed test ?

Comment: Eventually this is going to be running on my CLI Beaglebone, so the webpage options are out, and I'd like to log the results locally, so that also disqualifies the pages I've found. 

Pretty sure ping isn't what I'm looking for, I'm not looking for a response I'm looking for performance.

Comment: Depends, ping will tell you about the performance in that it shows a transit time. It depends on what you are trying to measure. Your question is vague. perhaps you want ab ?

Comment: ab looks interesting, but I don't have a server with a well-characterized response time like testmy does to work with. I'm more looking for how to format the output from wget into that time-speed(-variance) format I want for data collection before it gets appended to the log file. Decently new to linux, never had to do this before, so probably no deep meditation to understand the true nature of the question is needed, it should be simple!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful for someone, as I came here looking for an answer:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --report-speed=bits --show-progress -a speedtest.log -O /dev/null https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
```

Output of ***cat speedtest.log*** will be short enough:

```
--2022-08-25 19:15:08--  https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
Resolving speed.hetzner.de (speed.hetzner.de)... 88.198.248.254, 2a01:4f8:0:59ed::2
Connecting to speed.hetzner.de (speed.hetzner.de)|88.198.248.254|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104857600 (100M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’


2022-08-25 19:15:50 (20.2 Mb/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [104857600/104857600]
```

Note, that in this case, the speed is displayed in Mbps, since the *--report-speed=bits* option was used. You can remove it, to get speed in MBytes per second.

Answer (score 0):

Use the '-q' or `--quiet` option for wget. Like: `wget -O /dev/null --quiet --show-progress --report-speed=bits --no-cache http://speedtest.atlanta.linode.com/1GB-atlanta.bin`